# How to grab ng-binds output text from a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In most of my application I'm using ng-bind to display the data in my application of curly interpolation `{{ }}` in my templates instead o. I attempted to grab the interpolated ng-bind value from my element, however I keep getting undefined. Here is a JSbin of my [code](http://jsbin.com/nulikadaza/edit?html,js,output) (suggestion:open web dev console):

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller as vm">
      <section directit>
        <p ng-bind="vm.value"></p>      
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('controller', function(){
    this.value = 'hello';
  })
  .directive('directit', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope,element,atts){
        var p = element.children()[0]; 
        console.log('pText',p.innerHTML); //undefined
        console.log('p',[p]); //innerText value is defined upon inspection
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: It looks like the jsbin works fine for me. No errors in console. What exactly is your issue? If you're just trying to get the text of the `ng-bind` within the `directit` directive, then just set `directit="task"` and set up two way scope binding in the directive. Then the directive can place the `<span ng-bind="task.status"></span>` inside of the element, or whatever.

Comment: Ahh I updated the bin a few hours later without realizing. The code posted with my question was the code that wasn't working. `scope.$eval` solved my problem